# How do I debug my typescript pages with Chrome DevTools for a .NET Core web application?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, angular7

I am adding functionality to an existing Angular 7 application.  However I need to be able to debug the typescript to check the values from an object or array. How do I enable Chrome Dev tools to be able to debug my ts files?

Answer (score 0):

> However I need to be able to debug the typescript to check the values from an object or array. How do I enable Chrome Dev tools to be able to debug my ts files?

I'm not sure there's anything you need to enable. I'm tinkering on an Angular 7 app right now. Here are some workflows that you might find helpful.

Adding `debugger` statements into your code is probably the most straightforward approach. As Chrome executes the page, if it encounters a `debugger` statement while DevTools is open, it'll pause on that line of code.

[image: debugger]

In the screenshot above I added the `debugger` statement to a `click` listener, so the page only paused after I clicked the button. The **Call Stack** pane shows the calls leading up to the moment in time where I paused. The **Scope** pane shows what variables are in scope.

While paused you can press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to run JS in the Console. The context also matches the point in time where you are paused. For example in the screenshot below you can see that `this` resolves to the component that I'm paused in.

[image: Console]

Setting breakpoints from the DevTools UI, seems to work, too. To open my source file I navigated to `webpack://` > `.` > `src` > `app`

I haven't worked extensively with Angular so these workflows may not work if you're using a different development environment than the default `ng serve --open`.

Let me know if any of these help or don't work.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to debug the transpiled JavaScript as its all converted in the build process. You can see that in the 'sources' section of the debug tab where you'll be able to add breakpoints and all the stuff there. If you want to find a section easily just log it and the console should give you the JavaScript line  eg.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This only works in local:

- Firstly open application in Chrome
- Open dev tools
- Click on Sources
  [image: sources on chrome dev tools tabs]
- Press Ctrl+P and write the file name you want to debug
- If you have troubles on finding, use the left side Filesystem to find it.
- Click on the line you want to debug.
- Chrome will generally stop there, but in React you may have troubles, since it runs in a declarative way, maybe Angular may cause the same problem.